# store event in native calendar of iPhone using EventKit.framework

Tags: iphone, ios, events, calendar, eventkit

I am trying to save event in iPhone calendar using EventKit.framework. Its save perfectly, but I want to set alert to "NONE", but by default it takes '30 minutes before' as alert. How can I solve this problem? Here is my code to save event in iPhone calendar

```
if ([appDelegate.objEvent.event_alert intValue]==0) {
        alarm1 = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:0];
    }
    else if ([appDelegate.objEvent.event_alert intValue]==1) {
        alarm1 = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:-5];
    }
    else if ([appDelegate.objEvent.event_alert intValue]==2) {
        alarm1 = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:-300];
    }
    else if ([appDelegate.objEvent.event_alert intValue]==3) {
        alarm1 = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:-900];
    }
    else if ([appDelegate.objEvent.event_alert intValue]==4) {
        alarm1 = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:-1800];
    }
    else if ([appDelegate.objEvent.event_alert intValue]==5) {
        alarm1 = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:-3600];
    }
    else if ([appDelegate.objEvent.event_alert intValue]==6) {
        alarm1 = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:-7200];
    }
    else if ([appDelegate.objEvent.event_alert intValue]==7) {
        alarm1 = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:-86400];
    }
    else if ([appDelegate.objEvent.event_alert intValue]==8) {//B4 2 days
        alarm1 = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:-172800];
    }

    NSMutableArray *myAlarmsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//    [myAlarmsArray addObject:alarm1];

//    event.alarms = myAlarmsArray;
//    [myAlarmsArray release];

    if ([appDelegate.objEvent.event_alert intValue]!=0)
    {
        [myAlarmsArray addObject:alarm1];
        event.alarms = myAlarmsArray;
    }
    else
    {
//        [myAlarmsArray addObject:nil];
//        event.alarms = nil;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation, If you want an alert to fire at, as you say NONE, which i assume you mean to fire at the exact time that the event is, you would use the following code

```
[EKAlarm alarmWithAbsoluteDate:date];
```

[Link to the documentation for this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKAlarmClassRef/EKAlarmClassReference/EKAlarmClassReference.html)

Comment: no, I don't want to fire alert at any time. please check iPhone calendar, create new event where ALERT set to NONE, Not the time of the event.

Comment: Not sure what you are really asking for anymore but check out the following documentation, it might help you out.  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html